# Unable to determine the serialization information when trying to query the child MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Um sharing my code Im using to query  and get a matching child element to do an update to an element in an array in mongoDB Collection

```
                var filter = Builders<Fruit>.Filter.Eq( x => x.Id, fruitId );
                var update = Builders<Fruit>.Update.Set( x => x.FruitDetails.FirstOrDefault( y => y.Id.Equals( FruitDetail.Id ) ), FruitDetail );
```

Unfortunately this throws an  error in Update Linq Query and i do not know how to fix this

```
   Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: (Fruit x) => Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<FruitDetails>(x.FruitDetails, (Fruit p) => p.Id.Equals(<mongoID>)).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this bug in MongoDB JIRA and seems like this is not possible yet to achieve using MongoDB C# driver https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-723